# PHP PDO Update Statement not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

This is probably an easy thing for you geniuses, but I have tried all of the ways I know and can't get this UPDATE Statement to work. The problem is with the update statement or the execute binding. I want the statement to add 2 points to the user's points column.

```
<?php
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=App;host=localhost;charset=utf8', '*', '*');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$points = 2;
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$response = array();
$stmt->$dbConnection->prepare("UPDATE user SET points = points + ? WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($points, $username, $password));
$hi = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT username, password, points FROM user WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$hi->execute(array($username, $password));
$red = $hi->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($red) > 0){
    $response["success"] = true;
    foreach($red as $item) {
        $response["username"] = $item["username"];
        $response["password"] = $item["password"];
        $asd = $item["points"];
        $response["points"] = (string)$asd;
    }
}else{
    $response["success"] = false;
}
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign $stmt to the prepared statement from the connection

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("UPDATE user SET points = points + ? WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
```

Comment: Yeah, you got it! Stupid mistake, didn't see it at all! I feel dumb af right now!      I have to wait 3 minutes before I can accept your answer. Thanks for your help!