# PHP PDO error on line 18

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is the error code that I'm receiving when I run the code below!

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'points' doesn't have a default value in /var/www/html/public_html/register.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/public_html/register.php(18): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/public_html/register.php on line 18

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$dbConnection = new PDO('mysql:dbname=App;host=localhost;charset=utf8', '*', '*');
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$email = "sexyi";
$username = "sexyi";
$password = "sexyi";
$response = array();
$hi = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? OR email = ?");
$hi->execute(array($username, $email));
$red = $hi->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if (count($red) > 0){
    $response["success"] = false;
}else{
    $response["success"] = true;
    $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO user (email, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($email, $username, $password));
}
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: It may be your table  have a field "point "  which you do not set the value .check you database table please .

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP PDO Update Statement not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702589/php-pdo-update-statement-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation for the error is table `user`. That likely includes a column named `points`. And the column is declared as NOT NULL and there is no DEFAULT value specified. (MySQL would use the DEFAULT value when a value isn't supplied for the column.)

(If there's a BEFORE INSERT trigger on the table, then it might not be the `user` table, but some other table referenced in the trigger.)

To fix this issue, several options:

- include the `points` column in the INSERT, and provide a value

  `INSERT INTO user (..., points) VALUES (..., '0')`
- change the table definition to allow NULL value for `points` (remove NOT NULL constraint)

  `ALTER TABLE CHANGE points points datatype COMMENT ''`
- change the table definition to specify a DEFAULT value

  `ALTER TABLE CHANGE points points datatype NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'foo'`

(Replace `datatype` with the current datatype assigned to the column, whatever that is... e.g. `INT`, `DECIMAL(20,2)`, `VARCHAR(40)`

Comment: Their other question is relevant to their present question http://stackoverflow.com/q/43702589/1415724